# Need help with simple PHP plugin

Tags: plugin-development, templating, plugins, php

I'm not a plugin developer, nor is my knowledge of PHP sufficient to handle this issue.

I need a simple method or plugin, to be able to generate this PHP code in a template.

```
<?
$params="";

foreach($_POST as $name=>$value)
{
    if ($name!="controllerPage")
    {
        $params=$params.$name."=".$value."&";
    }
}
?>
```

In the same template I need this code to retrieve the above

```
<? echo $params; ?>
```

Who can show me the way?

This is the POST data that is attached to the URL

```
$_POST=array (
'view' => 'SearchResult',
'controllerPage' => 'https://navigantes.eu/yachts-search',
'customCssPath' => 'https://navigantes.eu/css/booking-manager-small.css',
'setlang' => 'en',
'target' => '_blank',
'companyid' => '1234',
'filter_country' => 'HR',
'filter_region' => '',
'filter_base' => '',
'filter_year' => '2016',
'filter_month' => '11',
'filter_date' => '10',
'filter_duration' => '7',
'filter_flexibility' => 'on_day',
)
```

Which needs to be translated to this:

```
view=SearchResult&amp;customCssPath=https://navigantes.eu/css/booking-manager-small.css&amp;setlang=en&amp;target=_blank&amp;companyid=1234&amp;filter_country=HR&amp;filter_region=&amp;filter_base=&amp;filter_year=2016&amp;filter_month=11&amp;filter_date=10&amp;filter_duration=7&amp;filter_flexibility=on_day&
```

Solved the issue by using {{ craft.request.getPost('') }} method:

```
            <iframe name="" width="100%" height="800" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"
            src="https://www.booking-manager.com/wbm2/page.html?
                view={{ craft.request.getPost( 'view' ) }}&
                customCssPath={{ craft.config.environmentVariables.rootUrl }}/css/booking-manager-small.css&
                setlang={{ craft.request.getPost( 'setlang' ) }}&
                companyid={{ craft.request.getPost( 'companyid' ) }}&
                filter_country={{ craft.request.getPost( 'filter_country' ) }}&
                filter_region={{ craft.request.getPost( 'filter_region' ) }}&
                filter_base={{ craft.request.getPost( 'filter_base' ) }}&
                filter_year={{ craft.request.getPost( 'filter_year' ) }}&
                filter_month={{ craft.request.getPost( 'filter_month' ) }}&
                filter_date={{ craft.request.getPost( 'filter_date' ) }}&
                filter_duration={{ craft.request.getPost( 'filter_duration' ) }}&
                filter_flexibility={{ craft.request.getPost( 'filter_flexibility' ) }}&
            ">
        </iframe>
```

And finally Brad's suggested method worked by changing craft.request.getSegments() into craft.request.getPost():

```
{% set segments = craft.request.getPost() %}
{% set stringParams = '' %}

{% for name, segment in segments %}
{% if name != 'controllerPage' %}
    {% set stringParams = stringParams ~ name ~ '=' ~ segment ~ '&' %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

<iframe name="" width="100%" height="800" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" src="https://www.booking-manager.com/wbm2/page.html?{{ stringParams }}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100% untested, but something like this should work:

```
{% set segments = craft.request.getPost() %}
{% set stringParams = '' %}

{% for name, segment in segments %}
    {% if name not 'controllerPage' %}
        {% set stringParams = stringParams ~ name ~ '=' ~ segment ~ '&'
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: for some reason it doesn't recognise the name variable. I solved the issue in a more complex way ;-)

Comment: By changing craft.request.getSegments() to craft.request.getPost() I was able to get it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do this in the template by using for example:

```
craft.request.getSegments
```

or

```
craft.request.getParam( name )
```

See the docs:

https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.request

Comment: Getting a Array to string conversion error using the above.